# POST file data, text data and variable data via Ajax to PHP file for Upload

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have three type of inputs those are file input, text input and variable. I want to upload those inputs by sending data to PHP file by using Ajax JSON. Also I want to know how to capture these data in PHP file.

I am using HTML code without form syntax. variable data name as a val1 in JQuery code.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="container" id="post">
    <textarea id="posttext" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" multiple accept=".mp4, .mov, .m4v, .MPEG-4, .gif, .jpg, .png"/>
    <button type="button" id="submitpost">Submit</button>
</div>
```

JQuery Code:

```
$(document).on("click", "#submitpost", function(){
    var val1 = "Some Datas";

        $.ajax({
        url: post.php,
        type: 'POST',
        data: VALUES,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data)
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
        });
});
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['VALUES']) && !empty($_POST['VALUES'])) {
        $params = $_POST['VALUES'];

}
?>
```

How to get each values in PHP to Upload files and insert text and variable data to database.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

**Html:**

```
<div class="container" id="post">
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" id="myform">
    <textarea id="posttext" name="posttext" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" multiple accept=".mp4, .mov, .m4v, .MPEG-4, .gif, .jpg, .png"/>
    <button type="submit" name="submitpost" id="submitpost">Submit</button>
   </form>
</div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).on("click", "#submitpost", function(e){
    $("form#myform").submit();
});
$("form#myform").on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var val1 = "Some Data";
    var file = this.files[0];
    var form = new FormData();
    form.append('file', file);
    form.append('val1', val1);
    form.append('posttext', $('#posttext').val());
    $.ajax({
        url : "post.php",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data : form,
        success: function(response){
            alert(response);
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
    print_r($_POST);
    print_r($_FILES);
}
?>
```

Comment: where is the variable data (val1)\

Comment: ajax is working i put each "Text" code in php file and I get Text response but not values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150527/discussion-between-ind-and-ckg).

Comment: I got response like this Array ( [file] => undefined [val1] => Some Data [posttext] => jjj ) Array ( ) but file is undefined

Comment: I use var file = this.files; like this. I got error for var file = this.files[0];